# xml and include and then xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

I have three xml files, that I need to XSLT 2.0 as ONE file. They are parts of the same book chapter. Can I have XSLT see them as one file ? (eg. some Include?). Would be much easier than write an XSLT template that would do the trick.

Answer (score 2):

XML has some inclusion mechanisms like external entities e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE root [
  <!ENTITY chapter11 SYSTEM "chapter1-1.xml">
  <!ENTITY chapter12 SYSTEM "chapter1-2.xml">
  <!ENTITY chapter13 SYSTEM "chapter1-3.xml">
]>
<root>
  <chapter>
    &chapter11;
    &chapter12;
    &chapter13;
  </chapter>
</root>
```

or XInclude. It all depends on the XML parser you use or can plug into to your chain of tools you use with your XSLT processor.

Within XSLT you can of course do e.g.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="(doc('chapter1-1.xml'), doc('chapter1-2.xml'), doc('chapter1-3.xml')//p"/>
</xsl:template>
```

without the need to have the XML parser support an inclusion mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

Or in XSLT you can define a global variable to hold the merged document:

```
<xsl:variable name="merged">
  <doc>
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc('doc1.xml')"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc('doc2.xml')"/>
    <xsl:copy-of select="doc('doc3.xml')"/>
  </doc>
</xsl:variable>
```

Comment: Can this by done dynamically, such as 'all files in a folder matching doc*.xml', or as a comma-separated list passed as a parameter?

Comment: Use the collection() function, though it's not 100% portable. In Saxon, `collection('.?select=doc*.xml')`